# Reactjs - Object Keys - how to ketrive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using

```
data.map(counter=>key={counter.id},value={counter.value})
```

to create the objects through the Counter component.
I can access prop values from the object but I cannot access the key. Why?
When I `console.log(this)`, it retrives an object that have a `key`, but, `this.key`, or `this.props.key`, retrieves `undefined`. And `this.props.value` retrieves correctly.

```
  const data = [
  { id: 1, value: 0 },
  { id: 2, value: 2 },
  { id: 3, value: 0 }
];

class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
    console.log(this)
      console.log(this.props.key)
       console.log(this.props.value)

      return(<h1>test</h1>)
          }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
        return (
      <div>
        { data.map(counter => (
           <Counter 
            key={counter.id}
              value={counter.value} 
            />
        ))}
      </div>); 
  }
}
```

Comment: This code `data.map(counter=>key={counter.id},value={counter.value})` will produce a syntax error without creating an expression within `.map()` callback function.

Comment: `key` in react are not passed as props, they used it internally. Consider passing `id` props instead

Answer (score 2):

A component can't access its own key, since it's used as a special prop by React itself to track components. It's not meant to be used as a regular prop, so React doesn't give you access to it.

If you need to access it as a prop then pass it in as another prop with a different name.

Comment: In this case, why we use the key?

Comment: You can *assign* keys, which tells React what to use as the key. You just can't fetch it in the child. By assigning a key we can control how React tracks the components, which is usually one for arrays of components so React can track each individual element of the array properly.